# getting error on server while using ngx-chips TagInput and working in local

Tags: angular, npm

I am using ngx-chips TagInputModule it is all working fine in local but after creating build and uploaded on server it is giving error message

```
ERROR ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
    at new nn (13.f32f0b79e2d4a8f8670a.js:1)
    at ZC (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at WC (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at Ex (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at Object.wx [as createEmbeddedView] (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at kC.createEmbeddedView (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at wC.createEmbeddedView (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at Lt._updateView (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at Lt.set ngIf [as ngIf] (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
    at tx (main.7b9061a5e3a320cca72c.js:1)
```

Can you help me with solution for this or is there similar package to use?

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10193 Try change `"buildOptimizer": false`  in `angular.json` file.

Comment: @hrdkisback, Thanks that worked for me, just want to clarify that will it be affecting to project in any case?

Comment: Yeah I think it increases your build size.